# Laravel - append join query after executing a query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

Is that possible in laravel to append another query to a query already exceuted?!
I have a query with joins but the last join I want to excute is a one to many join so for preventing any duplicates I want to append this join to the query in array for example.

```
$this->model::leftjoin('Route', 'Route.RouteID', 'Trip.RouteID')
            ->leftjoin('ReferenceTrip', 'ReferenceTrip.ReferenceTripID', 'Trip.ReferenceTripID')
            ->leftjoin('route', 'route.uuid','ReferenceTripGroup.route_id')
            ->leftjoin('tolls', 'tolls.route_id', 'route.uuid')->get();
```

the last line
`->leftjoin('tolls', 'tolls.route_id', 'route.uuid');` is many so it will cause duplicates, is there any solution.

also if there is any solution I will consider to use `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: Have you looked at [the `distinct` query builder method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects)?

Comment: distinct will remove all the duplicates depends on the specific column so I will get on row only but actually I need all the rows with additional array has the tolls relationship